# Every time I launch a new project this error pops up about installing django packages

Tags: python, django

[image]

Is there any issue with library packages.

Comment: It's not a good practice to post a picture, please replace it with the textual content of the error :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a old version of python (from the image I can see you're using v2.6 that no one support anymore). See the table reported in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django) to know which python version are supported for the particular django distribution you're using.